# Why am i getting error: cannot find symbol for JComponent?

Tags: java, swing, compiler-errors, awt, jcomponent

I'm reading a O'reailly java textbook named Learning Java
I followed its instruction to make a graphic Hello World by creating own class HelloComponent to reaplce the JLabel class

I can't compile the HelloComponent class. It's giving me error:cannot find symbol on JComponent

Here are the codes.

File：HelloComponent.java

```
import java.awt.*;
class HelloComponent extends JComponent
{
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {
        g.drawString("Hello World", 125, 95);
    }
}
```

File: HelloWorld3.java

```
import javax.swing.*;

public class HelloWorld3
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Hello World!");
        frame.add(new HelloComponent());
        frame.setSize(300, 300);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

JComponent is in the package `javax.swing.JComponent`, this is not imported.

Comment: JComponent hierarchy is : java.lang.Object<-java.awt.Component<-java.awt.Container<-javax.swing.JComponent